# How to refactor for-loop async/await with Promise.all()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to use Promise.all() in this code. I've read on articles that you can run async operations in parallel with Promise.all() to optimize for speed. Here's the current code in nested for-loops (bad):

```js
type ListGroup = {
  listId: string
  groupIds: Array<string>
}

const listsAndGroups: Array<ListGroup> = []; // <-- put everything here

const { lists } = await mailchimp.get('/lists');
for (const list of lists) {
  const listObj = { listId: list.id };
  const { categories } = await mailchimp.get(
    `/lists/${list.id}/interest-categories`,
  );
  for (const category of categories) {
    const { interests } = await mailchimp.get(
      `/lists/${list.id}/interest-categories/${category.id}/interests`,
    );
    Object.defineProperty(listObj, 'groupIds', {
      value: interests.map((interest) => interest.id),
      enumerable: true,
    });
  }
  listsAndGroups.push(listObj);
}
```

Here's how I'm doing so far, I think I'm just running blindly here without really knowing what I'm doing:

```js
const listsAndGroups: Array<ListGroup> = await getListsGroups(); // <-- put everything here

const getListsGroups = async () => {
  const { lists } = await mailchimp.get('/lists');
  const listGroups = lists.map((list) =>
    getCategories(list.id).then((groups) =>
      groups.map((group: Record<'groupIds', string>) => {
        return {
          listId: list.id,
          ...group,
        };
      }),
    ),
  );
  return Promise.all(listGroups);
};

const getCategories = async (listId: string) => {
  const { categories } = await mailchimp.get(
    `/lists/${listId}/interest-categories`,
  );
  const groups = categories.map((category) =>
    getInterests(listId, category.id),
  );
  return Promise.all(groups);
};

const getInterests = async (listId: string, categoryId: string) => {
  const { interests } = await mailchimp.get(
    `/lists/${listId}/interest-categories/${categoryId}/interests`,
  );
  return { groupIds: interests.map((interest) => interest.id) };
};
```

Comment: This looks good! Except for accessing your `const`s as `this.…`, everything should work - does it not?

Comment: @Bergi thanks! It works but I just wanted to get a second opinion. It became much longer and I was wondering if there was a shorter way. (Also, I have `this` in front of my function calls because this was originally in a class haha I just refactored the code for the question)

Comment: I'm also using two Promise.all() statements and wanted to know if one Promise.all() would work to get the array of lists (which contains groups which has an array of interests). I'm still confused on how to do that since one depends on the other async function's results

Comment: You can shorten it a bit by not using temporary variables for the arrays that you pass to `Promise.all`, and by having `getInterests` return the right object (containing the `listId`) so that you don't need to `map` over the results of `getCategories` again.

Comment: And no, you cannot use a single `Promise.all`, just like you cannot use only a single loop in your original code.

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify your operation many way, Here is one:

```
type ListGroup = {
    listId: string
    groupIds: Array<string>
}

const listsAndGroups: Array<ListGroup> = []; // <-- put everything here
const { lists } = await mailchimp.get('/lists');

const pandingLists = lists.map(list =>
    mailchimp.get(`/lists/${list.id}/interest-categories`)
        .then(data => [data, { listId: list.id }])
);

for (const [{ categories }, listObj] of await Promise.all(pandingLists)) {
    const batch = categories.map(({ id }) =>
        mailchimp.get(`/lists/${listObj.listId}/interest-categories/${id}/interests`).then(interests => {
            Object.defineProperty(listObj, 'groupIds', {
                value: interests.map(({ id }) => id),
                enumerable: true,
            });
        }));

    await Promise.all(batch).then(() => listsAndGroups.push(listObj));
}
```

Comment: This executes the batches sequentially though, unlike the OP's attempt